# Verb order in passive future subordinate clause

Tags: word-order, passive, future

Say I want to express the following subordinate clause:

> … , that these texts will be read.

The standard word order would be:

> … , dass diese Texte gelesen werden werden.

But it sounds cumbersome. However, there are some cases ([multiple infinitives or *Ersatzinfinitiv*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html?MenuId=Sentence52#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882)) where the finite verb in the subordinate clause exceptionally comes before the infinitives. I found no reference to the following possiblity:

> … , dass diese Texte werden gelesen werden.

But it does feel natural (as a speaker of German since 11 years). Is this suggested form correct? Or, could you suggest a better form than the double *werden* occurance in the original?

Comment: I'm afraif that in a subordinate clause the *werden gelesen werden* doesn't work, as the first *werden* is the finite verb. Is there no possibility to change the subordinate clause into a main clause or reformulate without passive or future tense?

Comment: Normally, you can just omit the second "werden" and it doesn't change the meaning. "..., dass diese Texte gelesen werden."

Comment: Sorry, but you're being misled by interference. Reordering the verb phrase like this is very much *not* natural. If you want to avoid the repetition for euphonic reasons, you must rephrase the passive, e.g. "...dass man diese Texte lesen wird".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my point of view, the following seems correct

> … , dass diese Texte gelesen werden werden.

It does *sound* pretty strange, however, and most people wouldn't say it. Yet, I have not found any rule that says it is wrong. On the other hand I did find [this table](http://conjd.cactus2000.de/showverb.php?verb=machen&var=0&pas=2&sen=2), which says for *Vorgangspassiv in Nebensätzen zu Aussagesätzen*:

> **Indikativ Futur I Passiv**
>   ich gemacht werden werde
>   du gemacht werden wirst
>   er/sie/es gemacht werden wird
>   wir gemacht werden werden
>   ihr gemacht werden werdet
>   **sie/Sie gemacht werden werden**

Replace *machen* by *lesen* and you get

> sie gelesen werden werden

Germans, however, tend to express the future by using the present tense, as the fact that something happens in the future is mostly clear from the context.

Examples:

> *Morgen gehen wir in den Zoo* instead of
>   *Morgen werden wir in den Zoo gehen*

So your sentence could be shortened to

> … , dass diese Texte gelesen werden.

Please note that there are sentences where this doesn't work nicely. For example if you want to say that books won't disappear and people will always read books you'd say:

> Es werden immer Bücher gelesen werden.

to stress that this will be true forever. If you just said

> Es werden immer Bücher gelesen.

this connotation is not so clear.

Comment: No, »dass diese Texte gelesen werden werden.« is not correct. If a student writes this in a German exam the teacher will mark it as an error.

Comment: Wir sind uns einig, dass noch in vielen Jahren von Lehrern Textstellen markiert werden werden... Aber da meine Frau zufällig Deutschlehrerin ist, werde ich sie gerne mal fragen.

Comment: Da ich keinen "Subscribe"-Button gefunden habe, dieser Kommentar, denn die Antwort Deiner Frau interessiert mich auch. Das Beispiel mit den Textstellen klingt m. E. recht natürlich, also nicht falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I edited my answer, because I actually found a source.

Comment: Ich bin zum gleichen Ergebnis gekommen wie Thorsten. Es klingt schräg und der Gebrauch des Vorgangs-Passiv im Futur ist unüblich, es ist aber auch in Nebensätzen zulässig und in in der angegebenen Form grammatikalisch korrekt.

Comment: Ihr habt mich überzeugt. Praktische Anwendung findet diese Konstruktion aber so gut wie gar nicht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das stimmt. Ich habe das auch noch niemanden sagen hören. Habe den diesbezüglichen Fehler in meiner Antwort auch gerade korrigiert (*wouldn't say it*  instead of *would say it*).

Comment: @Raketenolli Ich habe meine Frau noch nicht gefragt, da ich aufgrund der verlinkten Tabelle selbst überzeugt war, dass es stimmt.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar unter "lesen" http://conjd.cactus2000.de/showverb.php?verb=lesen&var=0&pas=2&sen=2 findet man ebenfalls diese Tabelle. Die Form scheint also durchaus möglich zu sein. Dein Hinweis mit der connotation ist aber auch wichtig, denn Regeln sind ja dazu da, dass man sie kennt, und bei Bedarf brechen kann ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Let's make a full sentence out of it:

> I hope, that these texts will be read.

In German this is:

> Ich hoffe, dass diese Texte gelesen werden.

Both of your proposals are wrong.

This construction technically gives no information if it is present tense or future tense. You can add »now« as well as »in some years« to make clear what tense is meant:

Let's try present tense. You are a teacher. An hour ago you asked your students to read some texts which will be subject of a test in an hour. You can't see the students now, but you hope, that in this very moment they do what you told them:

> Ich hoffe, dass diese Texte **jetzt** gelesen werden.

But you can also omit »jetzt«, and it still can be interpreted as present tense:

> Ich hoffe, dass diese Texte gelesen werden.

Other scenario: You are an author writing a book. The book is not finished, and until now nobody could red it. But you hope, that your texts will be read in a far future, once they will be published:

> Ich hoffe, dass diese Texte **in ein paar Jahren** gelesen werden.

But you can also omit »in ein paar Jahren«, and it still can be interpreted as future tense:

> Ich hoffe, dass diese Texte gelesen werden.

Comment: Noch in vielen Jahren werden deine Texte gerne gelesen werden.

Comment: "gelesen werden werden" felt wrong to me at first glance, but thinking of a different sentence structure (see the example by @ThorstenDittmar) clearly shows that it's not wrong. Still, you're right that the German translation drops the second "werden" because German makes use of a different tense.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: »Sie werden gelesen werden« ist richtig, aber »..., dass sie gelesen werden werden« ist falsch. Es ging in der Frage ja ausdrücklich um passive **Nebensätze**, nicht um Hauptsätze.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich weiß. Wenn Du mir jetzt noch die Grammatikregel sagen kannst, nach der das Nebensatz so und nicht anders gebildet wird, dann ändere ich gerne meine Antwort :-)

Comment: @Em1: Sorry, but Thorsten is wrong when telling you that »..., dass sie gelesen werden werden« would be right. No, this subordinate clause is wrong, and Thorsten is wrong too.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Wenn du es ohnehin weist, warum schreibst du dann in deiner Antwort das Gegenteil? Deine Antwort beginnt mit der Behauptung, dass »..., dass sie gelesen werden werden« korrekt sein, aber jetzt schreibst du in einem Kommentar, dass du eh weist, dass es falsch ist? Wir passt das zusammen?

Comment: Nein, ich meinte, ich weiß, dass es in der Frage um *Nebensätze* geht, mein Satz aber ein Hauptsatz ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Siehe Tabelle "Indikativ Futur I Passiv" auf http://conjd.cactus2000.de/showverb.php?verb=machen&var=0&pas=2&sen=2

Comment: Wenn etwas im Hauptsatz richtig ist, warum sollte es im Nebensatz falsch sein. Warum darf man im Haupsatz "werden [verb] werden" sagen, nicht aber im Nebensatz? Ist ja auch sonst nicht, bspw. "Ich werde Lehrer sein." ist nicht, "dass ich Lehrer sein." Da fällt doch das Futur-werden nicht einfach weg.

Comment: –1. Du hast zwar Recht, dass in der Regel Präsens statt Futur verwendet wird. Das macht das Futur aber nicht grammatikalisch falsch, nur unüblich. »… dass diese Texte gelesen werden werden« ist grammatikalisch korrekt, lediglich nicht üblich.